# What does it mean that (JSX) is a syntax extension to javascript in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was learning `React` and I came to know about `JSX`, The defination says that it is a syntax extension to javascript. What does it mean by syntax extension to javascript. Does it mean that the `React` has added new features to existing javascript for react development, or does it altogether a new language developed by the `React`,or it is seprate from react.

Comment: It means jsx is a new programming language that is based on javascript

Comment: Is JSX only created for react development or it is seprate from react.

Comment: React wouldn't be react without jsx. Jsx was created by Facebook as a templating language for their React framework. Jsx is basically javascript with built-in XML-like syntax. You can use the react library without jsx but that wouldn't be react development. Just go through one react tutorial and it would be obvious what jsx is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to explain what JSX is is to show an example of a JSX page. The following is a simple "Hello World" example in JSX:

```
function Title () {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>
}

function Content (text) {
    return <div>{text}</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<div><Title/><Content/></div>,document.body);
```

Now, a lot of the code above look like javascript but it's obviously invalid javascript right? Souldn't strings be wrapped in quotes like `"<h1>Hello</h1>"`? And what's with the weird `{text}` syntax? And what is a `<Content>` tag? Well, this is jsx. The `<h1>` element isn't a string but will be compiled into a javascript object by the jsx compiler. JSX is compiled down to javascript which can be sent to the browser to be executed.

There are two ways to use the jsx language: you can compile it to javascript using the jsx compiler or use a jsx parser in the browser to interpret the jsx in the browser. The second method is usually used during development or when debugging your web page. Normally you would pre-compile the jsx for production to speed up page loading and reduce the size of code the page needs to download.

Comment: Will that function in the above example like (Title and Content) will also come under JSX or that will that be just normal JavaScript. I mean to say that Is JSX only the return statement of function or the whole function will be called JSX, will every function we write inside react component will be JSX.

Comment: They will obviously cause syntax error in javascript because javascript will not understand the `<h1>`. This is the JSX language. When you are writing JSX the entire program is JSX but the language just looks like javascript. This is just like when you are writing C++ the entire program is C++ even though some of it looks like C

Comment: For example `console.log('hello')` is a valid JSX syntax. It is also valid javascript syntax. So just treat JSX like an extension, a superset of javascript

Answer (score 0):

As the definition says , JSX is an extension to Javascript. But what it implies is, at the end of the day when you look at a completed JSX file, you will realize that it is just plain Javascript plus HTML.

Now you may be wondering, HTML inside Javascript?!

Yes, You will be aware of the fact that the web browser can Understand only HTML, CSS and Javascript. But to develop amazing, feature rich, good looking web applications you will end up writing Huge HTML files with corresponding Javascript & CSS. In the long run, debugging and maintaining it will be a nightmare. That's where the developers who created React pitched in and tried to make matter simpler and decided to give you(the developer) more control & power.

In other words, JSX gives you more power and control while creating a React Web Application. I'm saying this from my experience, it will take sometime to get used to the weird syntax but when you become comfortable you will feel the power at your hands and fall in love with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a language, a separate language that is not JavaScript (though it is similar).

Like any language, it is executed by an executor program (also called compiler, interpreter, runner, etc). This program can't be Nodejs since it doesn't understand JSX.

The executor program can be a program written in JavaScript and itself being executed by Nodejs.

Babel is such an executor program that is run in Nodejs and transforms JSX into JS.